# openoffice-base setting the Criterion of a query column from a Form

Tags: openoffice-base

In an openoffice-base (ooBase) query, and in setting the Criterion of a column. How do I call a value from a Combo Box `[combo_1]` in a Form `[Form1]` to filter the query which produces my report?

In MSAccess it is `[Forms]![Form1].[combo_1]` but I can't find the syntax for ooBase any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this, and both of them are significantly more complicated compared to the MSAccess method.

The first way is to make the combo box save to one row of a filter table.  To ensure it always saves to the same one row the "Content type" for this form or subform will need to be "SQL command" with the "Content" something like `SELECT * FROM "Filter" WHERE "FilterID" = 1` (1, or whatever the primary key of the row you're using is).

Now set your query to have a join to that row of the filter table.

The second way is to use a macro.  On your combobox the macro will be triggered by the event "Item status changed", and the macro would read the combo box selection and put it where you need the data to go.